# Multiple conditional formating in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting, data-cleaning

[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qI7Uf.png)
[image]

Faced the obstacle with developing the formula on this table.

I am trying to apply conditional formatting to the E:F table and it would first need to look up and match number in the A and E column, after that is a match it needs to check if the number in F column matches either the number in the B or C columns.

For example, in the image provided, it would highlight F1 and F2.

Is this possible with conditional formatting or do I have to develop the tables differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or maybe:

Select ColumnF and: Format - Conditional formatting..., **Custom formula is** and:

```
=MATCH(E1,A:A,0)=IFERROR(MATCH(F1,B:B,0),MATCH(F1,C:C,0))
```

with highlighting of your choice. <kbd>Done</kbd>.

Comment: This look great at first but then I noticed that is highlighting the numbers in F column even if its not a match in B or C columns.

Comment: will need to look up the value from E1 and find it in the column A. Once it finds it in the column A it should highlight the value in the F1 it it matches either values in the columns B and C. (for example if it located that value from E1 is in A23, then it will  compare the value in F1 to the values in B23 and C23, if it exists-highlight.

Comment: Maybe I am looking at this problem from the wrong perspective, but I'm here to learn and if I am not being clear please let me know.

Comment: Good! Thank you both so much!

Comment: Yes!! Thank you SO MUCH!! If you have a resource that you can recommend for me so I can research and learn more about this topic I would appreciate it !! Thanks again!!!

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your problem correctly, you need to use a formula for condition formatting. Click on F1 cell and then click on Conditional Formatting -> New rule and then select Use a formula to determine which cells to format. Then use this formula

```
=IF(COUNTIF(E1,$A$1:$A$7);COUNTIF($B$1:$C$7,E1)>0,0)
```

Then you can use Format Painter to format the other cells in the table.

Here you can see the result.
[image]

Comment: Yes, I did. You probably need to use "," instead of ";" as a formula delimiter. I will update the solution.

Comment: True, this formula will only fork for the F1 and would compare to the B:C, we need the solution for the F2 and direct it to find the A1, THEN compare B:C

Comment: You're right, Format Painter did not delete an old rule I was testing before. Your formula probably matches the request better.

Comment: Does this formula work better?

`=IF(COUNTIF(E1;$A$1:$A$7);COUNTIF($B$1:$C$7;E1)>0;0)`